# Embedding Clickable PDF in Outlook 2010

Tags: pdf, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a PDF file with a monthly calendar on it. This calendar has event details and when a user clicks on a specific date, it takes them to a URL (where they register).

I'm trying to embed this PDF into an email rather than sending it as an attachment. When I embed this PDF in Outlook 2010, it appears to be embedded as a picture. I'm unable to click on any links within the PDF file.

Also tried inserting it as an object but get the same result. The PDF shows up but you can click on the dates to get to a URL.

Comment: havent u tried this http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/link-or-embed-files-HP003085344.aspx